# Is there any way to implement a get method inside a class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know if there is any way to implement a get method inside a class?

```
public class Element: IWebElement 
{
    IWebElement realElement;

    //Question point is this get{}
    //Everytime I access the instance of this class this get would be called
    get
    {

        //This 'realElement' is not present yet
        //So I cannot initialize it
        //But when the properties of this class are accessed
        //I'm telling the get method that it's time to initialize 'realElement'
        realElement = webDriver.FindElement(...);

        Visible = element.Visible;

        return this;
    }

    public bool Visible {get; set;}


}

public class AnotherClass()
{
    public void AccessElement()
    {
        Element element = new Element();
        if(element.Visible) // At this point the 'element'
        { 
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:
I cannot initialize every property with their own get, because they are too many

Comment: Is this a private method? Would you explain a case please for which you need it? Your question makes no sense to me because you can directly access an object from anywhere already.

Comment: What's the point of such a `get`?

Comment: Please reword your question. It is unclear what you are askig

Comment: Are you looking for [lazy initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

> Everytime I access the instance of this class this get would be called

If that could be done you'd be in trouble returning `this` since that would then access the instance, which would call the method, which would then access the instance, which would call the method… and so on until you get a `StackOverflowException` (or if it got tail-call optimised, forever).

More generally the question doesn't make sense.

A `get` method is a method identified as being the getter of a property. When C# is compiled to CIL then properties with getters are compiled so that there is a `.property` declaration with a `.get` declaration that refers to that method. If C# decided to change the rules to have getters on classes, it wouldn't have any corresponding CIL to compile it to.

The closest thing to a getter on a class in .NET is a default property, which in C# you can only have (and will always have) on a property called `this` (it becomes what is visible to other .NET languages or reflection property called `Item`), but it must have an indexer, and it does still exist as a property rather than with the getter directly applied to the class.

Comment: So, it looks like there's no way.

Comment: We cannot use this particular piece of code to throw `StackOverflowException`, no. Presuming that you don't want to just do that, what *do* you want to do? Maybe there's a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the constructor, so it will be called everytime instance of object will be created.

```
public class Element()
{
    public Element(){
             AnyProperty = ""; //some value initialize
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this new answer with my old answer because I got downvoted for trying to answer your original code which is now really different. Sheesh.

> Usage: I cannot initialize every property with their own get, because
>   they are too many

So, this is actually *not* how you usually use `get`. Get is used mostly for access to a private method, or with a little logic, and oftentimes for data-binding such as in MVVM, etc.

I think your wording is not accurate. You said

> Everytime I access the instance of this class this get would be called

But based on your code, what you mean is "Everytime I instantiate a class". The only thing you really need is a constructor.

```
public class Element: IWebElement 
{
    IWebElement realElement;
    public bool Visible {get; set;}
    public Element()
    {
        realElement = webDriver.FindElement(...);
        Visible = element.Visible;
    } 
}
```

---

**Old answer:**

You're probably thinking of the Singleton Pattern

EDIT: This originally answered original question's code, seen below.

```
public class Element()
{
 //Question point is this get{}
 //Everytime I access the instance of this class this get would be called
 get{

   return this;

 }

 public string AnyProperty {get; set;}

}

public class AnotherClass()
{

 public void AccessElement()
 {
  Element element = new Element();
  element.AnyProperty = ""; 
 }

}
```